# Mongo exception: connect failed on reboot

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have Mongo installed on Ubuntu 16.04 machine, on VMWare. I start it using "mongo" command, last week there was no problem. But recently, it gives this error:

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.15
connecting to: test
2017-08-09T09:31:33.634+0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-08-09T09:31:33.712+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed

I know how to solve it, it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831939/couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017/34835813#34835813

But everytime I reboot Ubuntu machine, the problem repeats. Why, and how can I prevent this happen everytime? 
Thanks.

Edit: Problem solved. You can see the solution below, in my comments to JJussi's answer.

Comment: So set the `mongod` service to start automatically on boot. Not really a programming question, hence it's actually answered on other sites. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61503/how-to-start-mongodb-server-on-system-start

Comment: I was automatically starting mongodb, using "sudo systemctl enable mongodb", now I also tried "sudo systemctl enable mongod.service" but it didn't work. Still I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`mongod` is actual mongodb daemon what "is" the database. `mongo` is just client program what connects to mongod process (in this case; with sharded cluster it connects to mongos -process).

So, `mongod` process must be running before `mongo` can connect it.

You wrote that `sudo systemctl enable mongod.service` don't work anymore? Check if that service has (some how) changed its name. Just give command `sudo systemctl|grep -i mongo` and you can see if it is there and it is enabled. IF still your mongod process don't start automatically after reboot, check /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log (you can check that lock file name with `sudo grep path /etc/mongod.conf` -command) says. What is the error? Fix that error (maybe chown of directory and files?) and try again with `sudo systemctl restart mongod.service` (or what ever is services name)

Comment: I think mongod has some problems. I'm trying to start it using `sudo systemctl start mongod.service`, when I check the status with `sudo systemctl status mongod.service`, this is the result:

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) 
Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
 mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
 mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: now I repaired mongod using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232668/8438046
Then I reboot computer and run mongo, no errors anymore, problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As MongoDB BOL [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) The MongoDB instance stores its data files in `/var/lib/mongodb` and its `log files` in `/var/log/mongodb` by default, and runs using the mongodb user account. You can specify alternate log and data file directories in `/etc/mongod.conf`.

If you change the user that runs the `MongoDB` process, you must modify the access control rights to the `/var/lib/mongodb` and `/var/log/mongodb` directories to give this user access to these directories.

Issue the following command to start mongod:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

For your further ref [Configuration File Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemLog.path)